# I am getting a missing ']' error when I run this shell script

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I am trying to run a shell script I made that would run a cpp file named cs216PA1.cpp. The only problem is that when I go to run it it stops at line 10 and says that there is no such file or directory. This is the line that calls the cpp file. Should I be doing something different to call it? Let me know what you guys think, because this is stumping me.

The shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Student Information Search..."
echo "Enter <Q or q> to quit the program."
echo "Enter any other key to continue..."

read usr_option
while [ "$usr_option" != "Q" && "$usr_option" != "q" ]
do
./cs216PA1

echo "Student Information Search..."
echo "Enter <Q or q> to quit the program."
echo "Enter any other key to continue..."
done
echo "Thank you for using the program!"
```

The cpp file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string id;
    cout<<"Please type the number of a student"<<endl;
    cin>>id;
    string name1[100];
    string name2[100];
    string courses[100];
    std::ifstream infile1("sec1students.txt");
    //infile1.open(sec1students.txt);
    if(!infile1)
    {
            cout<<"sec1students.txt file cannot be opened!";
            exit(0);
    }

    for (int num=0; infile1.good() && num<100;num++)
    {
            infile1>>name1[num];
    }
    infile1.close();
    for (int j=0; j<100;j++)
    {
            if (name1[j] == id)
            {
                    cout<<"Student number: "<<name1[j]<<endl;
                    cout<<"Name: "<<name1[j+2]<<", "<<name1[j+1]<<endl;
                    cout<<"Section: day-time"<<endl;
            }
    }
    std::ifstream infile2("sec2students.txt");
    //infile2.open(sec2students.txt);
    if(!infile2)
    {
            cout<<"sec2students.txt file cannot be opened!";
            exit(0);
    }
    for (int num=0; infile2.good() && num<100; num++)
    {
            infile2>>name2[num];
    }

    infile2.close();
    for (int j=0; j<100;j++)
    {
            if (name2[j] == id)
            {
                    cout<<"Student number: "<<name2[j]<<endl;
                    cout<<"Name: "<<name2[j+2]<<", "<<name2[j+1]<<endl;
                    cout<<"Section: evening"<<endl;
            }
    }
    std::ifstream infile3("studentcourses.txt");
    //infile3.open("studentcourses.txt");
    if(!infile3)
    {
            cout<<"studentcourses.txt file cannot be opened!";
            exit(0);
    }
    for (int num=0; infile3.good() && num<100; num++)
    {
            infile3>>courses[num];
    }
    infile3.close();
    int numb=6000000;
    for (int j=0; j<100;j++)
    {
            if (courses[j] == id)
            {
                    cout<<courses[j+1]<<endl;
                    numb=j;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if (numb==6000000)
    {
            cout<<"is not taking a course"<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You first compile the .cpp file and then execute the binary. What compiler do you use?

Comment: are both files in the same folder?

Comment: I am using vi. And yes, they are. But I got it figured out with the help of Blob down below. I just didnt compile it correctly to begin with.

Comment: Just a note: When using the `test` or `[` operator in bash, the compound test expressions are `-a` and `-o`. E.g. `expr1 -a expr2` -- True if both `expr1` and `expr2` are true. While bash will accept the `&&` `compound command` operator in this context, it is not an entirely correct use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a .cpp file. You feed it to a compiler which gives you an executable binary. Assuming you have g++, you'd do something like:

```
g++ cs216PA1.cpp
```

That will make a binary called "a.out". To give it the name "cs216PA1", which I suspect you want:

```
g++ cs216PA1.cpp -o cs216PA1
```

If you do the above (with the -o), your bash script should work assuming everything else is fine.

If you're using clang, you can just replace "g++" with "clang++".

Comment: Oh! thank you so much!! I just forgot to do that when I first compiled it and then forgot I didn't do it when  was writing the shell script. Thank you!